# What is the line of thinking to get $[(n^2+3n+1)^2-5n(n+1)^2]$ from $(n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, exponentiation, factoring

There is this one little tiny step along the working that I don't quite understand, but I think it is better if I write the whole problem and solution for clarity.

**Problem**: Factorize $5^{1995}-1$ into the product of $3$ integers, and every integer must be greater than $5^{100}$.

**Solution**: Let $5^{399}=n$. So,
\begin{align}
5^{1995}-1 &= (5^{399})^5 - 1\\
&= n^5-1\\  
&= (n-1)(n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1)\\
&= (n-1)[(n^2+3n+1)^2-5n(n+1)^2]\\ 
&= (n-1)[(n^2+3n+1)^2-5\times5^{399}\times(n+1)^2]\\
&=(n-1)[(n^2+3n+1)^2-5^{400}\times(n+1)^2]\\
&=(n-1)[n^2+3n+1+5^{200}(n+1)][n^2+3n+1-5^{200}(n+1)]\\ 
&=(5^{399}-1)(5^{798}+3\times5^{399}+5^{599}+5^{200}+1)((5^{798}+3\times5^{399}-5^{599}-5^{200}+1)
\end{align}
It is obvious that $5^{798}+3\times5^{399}+5^{599}+5^{200}+1>5^{100}$,
since $5^{399}-5^{100}=5^{100}\times(5^{299}-1)>5-1=4>1$, so $5^{399}-1>5^{100}$.
And since $(5^{798}+3\times5^{399}-5^{599}-5^{200}+1)-(5^{100}+1)$
$=5^{798}+3\times5^{399}-5^{599}-5^{200}-5^{100}$
$=(5^{798}-5^{599})+(5^{399}-5^{200})+(5^{399}-5^{100})+5^{399}>0$
so, $(5^{798}+3\times5^{399}-5^{599}-5^{200}+1)>5^{100}+1>5^{100}$.
So all the three factors are greater than $5^{100}$.

I understand the overall working, but I am wondering how can it get from $(n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1)$ to $[(n^2+3n+1)^2-5n(n+1)^2]$? Going backward is easy, but how about going forward? Does it use any formula or any tricks such as substitution or completing the square etc? In other words, what is the line of thinking? Or maybe are there any other alternatives?

Thanks so much! Helps are greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that they wanted to make $n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1$ a perfect square and used the fact that there are a lot of $5$s in the solution. Also, because $n = 5^{399}$, $5n = 5^{400}$, which is a nice square like $(n+1)^2$.

Comment: There is an easier method: $$5^{1995}-1=(5^{399}-1)(\cdots)=(5^{133}-1)(5^{266}+5^{133}+1)(\cdots)$$
Since each parentheses and $\cdots$ are greater  than $5^{100}$, we are done. Someone with the capabilities of doing the argument you present was either bored enough to do this proof, or showing off I think :)

Comment: What is the source of the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Note the splitting of the coefficients, you can replicate this technique with all sorts of monic polynomials:
\begin{align}
    n^4 + n^3 + n^2 + n + 1 &= n^4 + (6 - 5)n^3 + (11 - 10)n^2 + (6 - 5)n + 
    1\\
    &= \left(n^4 + 6n^3 + 11n^2 + 6n + 1\right) - \left(5n^3 + 10n^2 + 
       5n\right)\\
    &= \left(\left(n^2\right)^2 + (3 + 3)n^3 + (3^2 + 1 + 1)n^2 + (3 + 3)n + 1\right)\\
 &\hspace{20pt} - 5n\left(n^2 + (1 +1)n + 1\right)\\
    &= \left(n^2 + 3n + 1\right)^2 - 5n(n+1)^2.
\end{align}